# How can you temporary remove an iframe from a page, and later add the iframe back without re-downloading the iframe content?

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, iframe, detach

I have a page with some IFrames.  These IFrames are on the same domain.  I wanted to remove the iframe contents from the page when I opened a modal window, to reduce lag in the modal window.

And then, when I close the modal window, I'm hoping to reattach the IFrames to the page.

The problem is, every method I try re-downloads the IFrames when I reattach them.  I'm unsure if it's even possible to do this.

As an example, jQuery has a detach method that is supposed to not require you to download the content again, but this does not work.

```
var detatchWidgets =  $container.find("iframe");

detatchWidgets.detach();

msgDialog.on('hidden.bs.modal', function(){
    $container.append(detatchWidgets);    
});
```

Comment: _“jQuery has a detach method that is supposed to not require you to download the content again”_ – nothing in the docs for detach suggests that; it only says that it will keep any jQuery data that might be associated with the removed elements. Removing and then later on adding the elements again will in fact create _new_ elements, and that’s likely what causes the browser to request the sources again. // Have you tried if maybe simply settings the iframes to `display:none` (or `visibility:hidden`) might be enough to mitigate that “lag” you are talking about?

Comment: Thank you Brendan.  Yeah, you're correct about detach, I misread.  Im currently using display:none.  It works but, no where near as good as detach.  Problem with detatch is, it's great at first, but alas... the onslaught of HTTP requests and downloads when reattached.   I might end up listening for setTimeout and requestAnimationFrame and turning that off, as display:none doesnt seem to effect those, even though they are invisible.

Comment: Maybe this “onslaught of HTTP requests and downloads” would not be happening, if you instructed the browser to cache those resources (better)? Are you issuing any kind of caching instructions in the HTTP response headers for those resources currently?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion CBroe.  That is good advice.  In my case, all files are cached forever, or at least until they are modified... and I am also calling libraries like jquery from the iframes parent, without downloading jquery a second time inside the iframe... but there is still a lot on reattach.

Comment: _“or at least until they are modified”_ – I assume that means the browser has to at least make a conditional GET request and wait for a 304 Not Modified response from the server? You could maybe try and avoid that by going for “absolute” caching, instructing the browser not to do those conditional requests – and instead change the URLs when the content changes (adding a timestamp or hash of the content as GET parameter) server-side when the content actually has changed. (Of course then the user would only see changed content when they actually reload the parent page.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first of all, sorry if i missunderstand you.
just for testing i created 2 JSFIDDLE's:

1) i used as the src of the iframe, it alerts 2 sec after iframe loaded

https://jsfiddle.net/hr97240j/10/

```
setTimeout(function(){
    alert("loaded and iframe says hello");
},2000);
```

2) here is a page where the iframe is embbed.

https://jsfiddle.net/hr97240j/12/

in the 2nd i show the iframe, then hide it, after 3 sec i show it again, i can say, the src of the iframe is not reloaded again!
i see the contents of the iframe without any new alerts as in the first load.

Comment: Thank you Rami.  This seems to be the best way ( CBroe's suggestion of toggling display:none / display:block is faster, but does not remember element height like your jquery .show() and .hide() way ).   I wish there was a way to remove the iframe from the DOM entirely (similar to jQuery detach method) and reattach without re downloading iframe contents, but the more I think about it... the more I realize this is simply not possible or logical.